# how do I call a list of functions and use a string list ?

Tags: list, function

How do I call a list of functions and use a string list  ?

```
def apple_w():
    print(1)
def banana_w():
    print(2)
def orange_w():
    print(3)

fruits = ['apple','banana','orange']

for i in fruits:
.......
```

Comment: Please rephrase, what language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the syntax of your code I guess that you use python. There you have the `globals`-function, which returns a dict with all global entities.

```python
    def apple_w():
        print(1)
    def banana_w():
        print(2)
    def orange_w():
        print(3)

    fruits = ['apple','banana','orange']

    for i in fruits:
        fn = globals()[i + '_w'] # get the function
        fn() # call the function
```